# Can I retrieve an Xcode project I installed on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, development

I recently executed a stupid "Discard All Changes" on my Xcode project that resulted in the project being deleted.

I haven't found a way to recover it yet, but I was wondering since I had installed the Xcode project on my iPhone for testing, if there is any way I can take the project from the phone, or if it simply doesn't work like that.

The app still runs on my phone.

Comment: Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25308554/3487310).  It's similar to your issue and there's some answers there that might help.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the crummy thing about that is that it requires files to 1. Still be on your computer and 2. Capable of opening with TextEdit, and the current case doesn't fit either :(

Comment: Won't the application on your phone be the compiled version, not the source?

Comment: Although I wish you weren't, I think you're right. @ernie, you might as well post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

It should appear in the trash folder on your Mac. To access it click the trash icon in the dock.

You should be able to recover it there if you didn’t empty the trash.

Comment: Unfortunately git is more evil than that, the "Discard All Changes" option in Source Control doesn't leave anything in the trash can; it is currently empty (and I haven't emptied it since a couple hours before the "Discard All Changes" happened)

Comment: @bearacuda13 Have you tried connecting your device and browsing through files there?

Comment: I'm doing a backup right now that should be done in 11 minutes. Is there any way I can browse through the application with only a USB connection?

Comment: @bearacuda13 what do u mean